# unable get static image on webpage even after creating static folder and updating its path in settings.py and running collectstatic

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am using vscode.I created a django project named myproject, app named myapp and static folder in myproject dir. My image is not getting displayed in webpage after trying everything.I am not getting where is the issue please help.

my static folder location `C:\Users\nihar\myproject\static`

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

html file code

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<img src="{% static 'images/tttbg.jpg' %}">
</body>
```

Comment: You are missing an "S" from the end of the setting name - `STATICFILES_DIRS` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs

Comment: Also you did not mention STATIC_URL and urlpatterns for static files. Make sure you did not forget to set these options.

Comment: Thanks Ivon!!! Your observation made my code to work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Follow Bellow steps for load static in Django

```
# -------- handel Static Files In dajngo --------

# Steps:
    # 1 - Create (static) folder in Root Directory of Project
    # 2 - Paste Your Static Files Folder in (static) Folder (js,css,images...etc)
    # 3 - Now Do Setting in (setting.py)
           STATIC_URL = '/static/'
           STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
    # 4 - add {% load static %} tag on top of html page
    # 5 - Now use ({% static 'assets/image.jpg' %}) tag in HTML File for calling static files
    # 6 - Done
```